# How to crop image swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

in my project i have a UIImageView with square format for the image of the user profile, but when i add an image for example from the library, it appears shapeless. I have finded a code to crop the images to square format but i don't understand where to insert it in my code to crop the selected image from library or a new photo. Can you help me? 
Here the code:

**ImageUtil.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ImageUtil: NSObject {

 func cropToSquare(image originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    // Create a copy of the image without the imageOrientation property so it is in its native orientation (landscape)
    let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: originalImage.CGImage)!

    // Get the size of the contextImage
    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

    let posX: CGFloat
    let posY: CGFloat
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    // Check to see which length is the longest and create the offset based on that length, then set the width and height of our rect
    if contextSize.width > contextSize.height {
        posX = ((contextSize.width - contextSize.height) / 2)
        posY = 0
        width = contextSize.height
        height = contextSize.height
    } else {
        posX = 0
        posY = ((contextSize.height - contextSize.width) / 2)
        width = contextSize.width
        height = contextSize.width
    }

    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height)

    // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
    let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(contextImage.CGImage, rect)

    // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)!

    return image
}

}
```

**AddController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class AddController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, CameraManagerDelegate {


@IBOutlet var immagine: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var fieldNome: UITextField!


var immagineSelezionata : UIImage?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent

    navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 60/255.0, green: 172/255.0, blue: 183/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    //navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))

    //tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 60/255.0, green: 172/255.0, blue: 183/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)

    let singleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "selezionaFoto:")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    self.immagine.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    self.immagine.userInteractionEnabled = true

    fieldNome.delegate = self
    CameraManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self


    var keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
    keyboardToolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 60/255.0, green: 172/255.0, blue: 183/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    keyboardToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var flex = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var save = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Done", comment: ""),
        style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,
        target: fieldNome,
        action: "resignFirstResponder")
    keyboardToolbar.setItems([flex, save], animated: false)
    fieldNome.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
}

func myUIImageViewTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
        println("myUIImageView has been tapped by the user.")
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func annulla(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 
}




@IBAction func salva(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if fieldNome.text.isEmpty
        {

            return
    }

    var profilo = ProfiloModel(nomeIn: fieldNome.text,
        immagineIn: UIImage(named:"icon-profile")!)

    if let img = immagineSelezionata {
        profilo.immagine = img
    }



    //DataManager.sharedInstance.storage.insert(profilo, atIndex: 0)
    DataManager.sharedInstance.storage.append(profilo)
    DataManager.sharedInstance.salvaArray()
    DataManager.sharedInstance.master.tableView.reloadData()

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}




@IBAction func selezionaFoto(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    fieldNome.resignFirstResponder()

    func selezionaLibreria(action : UIAlertAction!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.Default, animated: true)
        CameraManager.sharedInstance.newImageFromLibraryForController(self, editing: false)
    }

    func scattaFoto(action : UIAlertAction!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.Default, animated: true)
        var circle = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        circle.image = UIImage(named: "overlay")
        CameraManager.sharedInstance.newImageShootForController(self, editing: false, overlay:circle)
    }

    var myActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("ACTION_IMAGE_TITLE", comment: ""),
        message: NSLocalizedString("ACTION_IMAGE_TEXT", comment: ""),
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("BUTTON_LIBRARY", comment: ""),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: selezionaLibreria))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("BUTTON_SHOOT", comment: ""),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: scattaFoto))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("BUTTON_CANCEL", comment: ""),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
        handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(myActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder() // chiudere la tastiera nei campi di testo
    return true
}

func incomingImage(image: UIImage) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
    immagine.image = image
    immagineSelezionata = image
}

func cancelImageSelection() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found a link can help you

> CGBitmapContextCreate & CGContextDrawImage
>
> Core Graphics / Quartz 2D offers a lower-level set of APIs that allow for more advanced configuration. Given a CGImage, a temporary bitmap context is used to render the scaled image, using CGBitmapContextCreate() and

```
CGBitmapContextCreateImage():

let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.URL.absoluteString!).CGImage

let width = CGImageGetWidth(image) / 2.0
let height = CGImageGetHeight(image) / 2.0
let bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image)
let bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image)
let colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image)
let bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image)

let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 

bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh)

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size:  CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))), image)

let scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context))
```

> CGBitmapContextCreate takes several arguments to construct a context with desired dimensions and amount of memory for each channel within a given colorspace. In the example, these values are fetched from the CGImage. Next, CGContextSetInterpolationQuality allows for the context to interpolate pixels at various levels of fidelity. In this case, kCGInterpolationHigh is passed for best results. CGContextDrawImage allows for the image to be drawn at a given size and position, allowing for the image to be cropped on a particular edge or to fit a set of image features, such as faces. Finally, CGBitmapContextCreateImage creates a CGImage from the context.

Font [Image Resizing Techiniques](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/)

Comment: @Elis perhaps this may help you in the future
https://github.com/pavankataria/ChopChop ?

Answer (score -1):

See [Image-Cropper](https://github.com/delhee/Image-Cropper).

Excerpt:

```m
func btnCropAndSaveClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("save btn clicked")

    let scale = 1 / scrollView.zoomScale

    let visibleRect = CGRect(
        x: (scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) * scale,
        y: (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top) * scale,
        width: CROP_WINDOW_WIDTH * scale,
        height: CROP_WINDOW_HEIGHT * scale)

    let imageRef: CGImageRef? = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(processedImage.CGImage, visibleRect)!

    let croppedImage:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil)
    showResultMessage()
}
```

That code allows you to zoom in and out the selected picture, move it around and crop the desired area of that picture. It's simple to implement, everything is done on the ViewController. Hope this solves your problem.